# Embedly Upending "Recommended" Videos on YouTube Embed

Tags: youtube, embedly

As far as I can tell Embedly just started upending "Recommended" video's at to the bottom of YouTube embeds on their "Cards" product. Any way to remove them?

[Embedly Recommended Videos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PGQK.jpg)

We are using Embedly as a third party service and thus have no access to edit the iFrame content of the card product. We cannot be displaying these recommended videos as it is not controllable, but seems to be randomly generated by Embedly. How do you remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else with this issue. You can add `data-card-recommend="0"` to the card.

http://embed.ly/docs/products/cards#customize